# Taking character input and given output using "NEW" and getting string length from user

Tags: c++, oop, new-operator

First I do this without getting length from user. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        char *str;
    cout<<"Enter Characters:";
    str=new char[];
    cin>>str;

    cout<<"\nstr="<<str;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Now I tried to take input length from user. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
        char *str;
    int len;

    cout<<"Enter Characters:";
    str=new char[];
    cin>>str;

    cout<<"Enter length of your entered character:";
    cin>>len;

    char *ptr=str;
    ptr=new char[len];

    cout<<"\nptr="<<ptr;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This show some odd things in output while "cout(ing)" "ptr", I don't know what!
If this is wrong, how can I also take input from user?
If I edit the first program, then I can't take input until this line "str=new char[];" is executed. And length can only be given in this line.
And length can only be given until string is taken.

Comment: `str=new char[];` - What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I made a space for char to store character.If i skip this line, i cant take str as input directly.

Comment: What compiler did you use?

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes, but the main is:

```
str = new char[];
```

This is not a valid C++ syntax. You should specify size of allocated memory. But if you don't know, how much memory you need, you should use `std::string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;

    std::cout << "str = " << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Another problem - every `new`ed memory should be `delete`d.

Comment: @user2429013: Ok, you should allocate for initial `size`, say, 64. Then read character by character until meet separator. If a character available, but memory is out, you should increase `size` and reallocate memory for string.

Comment: I think i should explain my question.I had to take input from user, a string, in a character pointer, and also the size of that string from user.and simply display it.